# Build all targets specified in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-multi-stage-build

Let's say I have a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM <some image> as base
COPY src /src
RUN <build command>

FROM base as test
RUN <test command>

FROM base as lint
RUN <lint command>

FROM base as <you get the idea>
RUN <test command>

FROM <slim-image> as production
COPY --from=base
```

I would like *one* command that runs *all* these targets, with BuildKit.

Is there an easy way, or would I have to script that?

Comment: @rbashish: your comment is wildly wrong. Also, if it were correct, it should have been posted as an answer with an explanation instead of a comment with only a command.

Comment: @rbashish: there is no docker-compose setup here.

Comment: @rbashish:  note that BuiltKit is mentioned as a requirement, which docker-compose does not support yet (see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6440). Also: there is no reason why using BuildKit with docker-compose would build *all* targets in *each* `Dockerfile`. One would assume that the behavior would be similar to only invoking `docker build`.

Comment: @rbashish: also, would it not be `docker-compose --build`? Neither `up` nor `-d` is relevant to what is being asked.

Comment: @rbashish: If it were acceptable to not use BuildKit then I would still not create a `docker-compose.yml` just for this. instead I would do `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build .`, which is basically what would currently happen "behind the scenes" when doing `docker-compose --build`.